# content_tag の float と decimal の扱いの違い

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`BigDecimal`を使用していると, `content_tag` で `data-*`を生成した時に文字列として出力されてしまい`float`との違いに気づきました。

```
<%= content_tag :div, 'b', data: {foo: '0.1'.to_f, bar: '0.1'.to_d} %>
<%= content_tag :div, 'a', data: {foo: ['0.1'.to_f], bar: ['0.1'.to_d]} %>
```

で以下のように出力されます。

```
<div data-foo="0.1" data-bar="0.1">b</div>
<div data-foo="[0.1]" data-bar="["0.1"]">a</div>
```

ソースコードを確認すると`ERB::Util.unwrapped_html_escape`が該当処理だと思うのですが、
違いが発生する原因が特定できませんでした。
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/861b70e92f4a1fc0e465ffcf2ee62680519c8f6f/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L103

対策としてはdecimalを使う時はfloatに変換してから出力すれば問題ないのですが、
何故このような差が発生するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

配列で与えた場合 (正確に言えば `String`, `Symbol`, `BigDecimal` 以外の場合) は`prefix_tag_option` 内で `.to_json` をコールしてます。これによって `Float` の場合はJSONの浮動小数点型に、`BigDecimal` はJSONの文字列に変換されています。

配列ではない場合、そのまま `tag_option` → `unwrapped_html_escape` に渡されて `.to_s` されるため、`Float` でも `BigDecimal` でも同じ挙動になります。(JSONにした場合でも `.to_s` はされるが、元々文字列なので変化はない。)

※ `.to_json` で `BigDecimal` が文字列に変換される理由は、`BigDecimal` に対応するJSONの型が存在しないためだと思います。(浮動小数点に変換すると誤差などが発生する)

Comment: なるほど、`#to_json`の 処理がそうなっているんですね。詳しい解説ありがとうございます。